# Why can't I seem to mix argv and randint?

Tags: python, argv

So I had my guessing game working and It wouldn't break regardless of input. i understand I can use the int function on the input but if the user decides to enter anything but an integer you get a runtime error so I did it different it was working until I decided I wanted to allow the user to add CLI arguments to define the value range for the integer generation it looks as below but it doesn't work...

```python
from sys import argv
import random
lower, upper = argv
lower = int(lower)
upper = int(upper)
secret_number = random.randint(lower, upper)
```

Output:

```text
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guess.py", line 3, in <module>
    lower, upper = argv
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I ran it with
python guess.py 1 100

this is the working version

```
import random
secret_number = random.randint(1,100) #assigns a random integer to secret_number
count = int(0) #starts the guess counter at 0
#print(f"the secret number is: {secret_number}")
print("Try and guess the number between 1-100")
number = input("please enter your guess: ")
while number != secret_number:
    try:
        count += 1  #same as count = count + 1
        number = int(number)
    except:
        print(f"you entered: {number}")
        number = input("please enter an integer only!: ")
    else:
        if number < secret_number:
            print(f"you entered: {number}")
            number = input("To Small! try again: ")
        elif number > secret_number:
            print(f"you entered: {number}")
            number = input("To big! try again: ")

print(f"you entered: {number}")
print("You Win! Congratulations!")
print(f"You took a total of {count} attempts to guess the number!")
```

Comment: Look at what `print(argv)` outputs.

Comment: A troubleshooting tip would be to inspect the contents of every variable sequentially until you find one that doesn't fit your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the first parameter of argv is the name of the script, so you want:

```
lower, upper = argv[1:]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

Comment: thanks i read the documentation file and saw that and was like.... well, that's silly. thank you though, I doubt I would've found it, i was getting frustrated. 2 damn chars... grrrr... i was so close :( BUT it works :D yay

but could you explain how the 1: works? does it set the start variable for the unpacking process? so instead of starting at 0 it starts at 1?